# Incomplete question title/big empty area

Tags: bug, android-app

When I look at questions with SE Android app v1.0.7, the question title is usually incomplete. After pulling down the question to refresh, I get a big empty area at the top of the question.

Before reloading

> [image: before reloading]

After reloading

> [image: after reloading]

You notice the incomplete question title more in landscape mode, but I decided to take the screenshots in portrait mode to see the whole empty area at the top.

I don't think I had the same problem before I updated to 1.0.7. Phone is a HTC One with Android 4.3.

Comment: Dub of one of my reports

Comment: Reproduces with 1.0.8. Samsung Mini S3 (GT-I8190T) Android 4.1.2
Possible dupe of 219865

Comment: I can reproduce this on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) running Android 4.3 (In landscape the title is completely gone, not just incomplete.) Running StackExchange app version 1.0.35